# Magnitude vs imaginary part of transfer function/ Green's function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

In quantum dynamics folks often examine the imaginary part of the Green's function to understand the response of a system. in classical mechanics / mechanical engineering folks often study the Bode plot which instead separates the transfer function into magnitude and phase. Why does one community focus on the imaginary part while the other community focuses on the magnitude of the transfer function?'/@#